# Permanent console on desktop as a "widget"

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, window-management

I just wondered whether it's possible to have a terminal window as a desktop applet (or desklet if you're using Linux Mint like me)?

I can't seem to find any info on it, ideally it would just be a term window with no border and not-movable in any way.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you asked if that is possible, then yes, it is, just sadly not in Cinnamon (as far as I know). But there is [a KDE widget like that](http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?content=142753) for KDE4.

If you don't want to switch to KDE, there is still an option: a drop down terminal. I'd prefer [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/blob/master/README.md), which is very lightweight, beautiful and customizable. You can easily install it with `sudo apt-get install tilda`. Adding it to startup and a few configuration could make it behave pretty much like an applet, but if you press Alt-F4 it will get closed so, well, that'd not be a perfect option.

Comment: Ok, how depressing :( Thanks - marked as an answer.